# XPathSelectElements => string representation

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xpath

Hi because of a misunderstanding I want to ask my question again.

I have the following XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
  <root>
    <Item>
      <taxids>
        <string>330</string>
        <string>374</string>
        <string>723</string>
        <string>1087</string>
        <string>1118</string>
        <string>1121</string>
      </taxids>
    </Item>
  </root>
</xml>
```

I need to get all the string nodes from the xml file to a string variable.

I want to get a string like this:

```
  <taxids><string>330</string><string>374</string><string>723</string><string>1087</string><string>1118</string><string>1121</string></taxids>
```

My linq to xml:

```
var query = from ip in doc.XPathSelectElements("xml/root/Item")
            select ip.XPathSelectElement("taxids").ToString();
```

But I am getting the following in one row of the variable query:

```
"System.Xml.XPath.XPathEvaluator+<EvaluateIterator>d__0`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]"
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a short but complete program that demonstrates your problem? I can't seem to produce the result you're seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = doc.Element("xml")
                .Element("root")
                .Element("Item")
                .Element("taxids")
                .ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);

// result == "<taxids><string>330</string><string>374</string> ... </taxids>"
```